# Probability calculation for genome sequencing

Tags: statistics

I am trying to calculate a P value to understand whether or not a DNA base read is correct at a given location. This is the math that I have been using:

$P=\sum_{k=k*}^n nCr(n,n-k)*(1-P)^k* P^{n-k}$

P is the probability that the base is correct from known error rates which is about 5%. Meaning that sequencers mis-identify 5% of bases.

K is the number of mismatches I see at a given location. In this example there are 5 mismatches.

n is the total bases read at a location. In this example there are 50 base calls, 5 are mismatches.

$P=\sum_{k=5}^{50} nCr(50,50-k)*(1-0.95)^k* 0.95^{50-k}$

Is this a correct way of calculating the probability that with 45 out of 50 calls being the same, that I am correct?

Comment: Well first off, your first formula doesnt make any sense. Way too many $P$s. Then, is $K$ = $k*$? The last formula $$P=\sum_{k=5}^{50} \binom{50}{50-k}(1-0.95)^k 0.95^{50-k}$$ gives you the probability that in 50 trials, where the chance of a misread is 5%, you'll have more than or exactly 5 misreads

Comment: @user159517 yeah i put p in the place of n in the first formula. And thanks that what I was hoping for.